# Producer and Client Connection

Tags: java, queue, consumer, producer

I have am working on a small project that will create a connection between a Producer and a Client. The producer will take an email object, put it in a queue, and the client will pick it up. I have two questions about this. There is a separate Email class not shown which just has one getter and setter method for a local String variable called content.

1) Why am I getting a null pointer exception in the line p.sendMessage(email), even though all the parameters are correct?

2) After the producer program has ended how will the values inside of the queue be stored so I can pick them up from the Client. Am I supposed to use some sort of server or database?

```
public class Producer {
    public static Queue que;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Producer p = new Producer();
        Email email = new Email("Content of email");
        p.sendMessage(email);
    }
    public void sendMessage(Email e){
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        String read = (gson.toJson(e));
        que.add(read);
    }
}

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client c = new Client();
        c.pickMessage();
    }
    public void pickMessage(){
        String s = Producer.que.remove().toString();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        Email newEmail = gson.fromJson(s,Email.class);
        System.out.println(newEmail.getEmailContent());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, add the NullPointerException call stack so we can check the point that the exception is thrown.

Comment: `que` is never assigned a value, returns NPE as expected.

Comment: So should I be running this on a server? I have never used a queue to communicate between two classes so am very new to this. Sorry for the silly questions.